# Can we add scrollbar to a single cell in Lightning Datatable?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, scrolling

I was working with Lightning Datatable in LWC and was just wondering is there any way we can add a horizontal scrollbar in a specific column of Lightning Datatable.

This is something we require in our current project.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to ensure that cell's column contains a [custom type](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_table_custom_types), where you use SLDS styling to make the cell content [scrollable](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/scrollable/), applying the styling to a `div` around your content that itself is set to an appropriate width and height.

Comment: Thanks @Phil W that's really helpful. I am working on it.